# What memory modules work in a Intel DP55WB?

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

I have an Intel DP55WB Motherboard with an i3 processor and two 2GB RAM cards (total 4GB).

I went to a store with my CPU to buy a 4GB RAM card in order to have a total of 8GB. The salesman unsuccessfully tried with cards of different brands, we also tried removing the two 2GB cards and starting the PC only with the one of 4GB, we verified the 4 slots work well by connecting the 2GB cards in different combinations.

Finally I came home with a 4GB kingstone card, I have to return it tomorrow if I cannot make it work, but I really think there must be something to do. I have the latest Bios update and one interesting thing is that I downloaded a previous version of the BIOS and with it the PC won't recognize one of the 2GB cards so I installed the latest BIOS back.

Please help me !!!

Comment: Did you make sure the 3 cards were in the correct slots? Check out page 36 of the [User Product Guide](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/18131/eng/DP55WB_ProductGuide04_English.pdf)

Comment: I did, I know there must be the same amount of RAM in channel A and channel B.

Comment: What you purchased isn't a "RAM Card" its a DDR3 module ( I assume its DDR3 otherwise its DDR2 ).

Comment: yes it is DDR3. But the question is, how to make PC to work with the complete 8GB ??

Comment: Can you tell us full the name of your new RAM/DDR3 module?

Comment: Here's what Kingston says will work: http://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search/discontinuedmodels?DeviceType=2&Mfr=INT&Line=DP55WB&Model=56618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the [specific memory requirements for your motherboard](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/DP55WB/sb/CS-030682.htm).  If you have trouble understanding the specifications, I suggest providing them to a professional.

Comment: SOLVED !!!

So in the file you shared it says I need double-sided memory modules (two rows of SDRAM) when using 4GB modules.

I got a "double-sided" module at another store and I finally have my 8GB !!!!

THANX !! :D :D :D

PS. I got my money back from the first store :P